# Android Java WiFi Get Gateway

Tags: java, android, wifi

```
byte[] bytes = BigInteger.valueOf(Wifi.getDhcpInfo().gateway).toByteArray();
InetAddress address = null;
```

Выдает только : /1.1.168.192, а я хочу 192.168.1.1. Как это сделать?

Comment: Сделать реверс массива.

Comment: обязательно нужно в байтах? `String gateway = String.valueOf(Wifi.getDhcpInfo().gateway);` не подходит?

Comment: вот код 'byte[] unpack(int bytes) {
    return new byte[] {
      (byte)((bytes >>> 24) & 0xff),
      (byte)((bytes >>> 16) & 0xff),
      (byte)((bytes >>>  8) & 0xff),
      (byte)((bytes       ) & 0xff)
    };
  } byte[] bytes = unpack(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Wifi.getDhcpInfo().gateway)));
    InetAddress address = null;
    try {
     address = InetAddress.getByAddress(bytes);
    } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }
    twMonitor.setText("Local Gateway: "+address);'

Comment: @GamerDeveloper дополни свой ответ, пожалуйста. Как ты понимаешь, такое читать невозможно